# Why is address sanitizer not detecting this simple memory leak?

Tags: c++, cmake, address-sanitizer

Does anybody have any idea why address sanitizer is not flagging this very obvious memory leak

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
};

TEST_F(LibrdfSerializerTests, Test) {
    A* a = new A;
}
```

built with the following added to cmake:

```
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
    set(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```

Comment: From [clang AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), Memory leaks detection is experimental.

Comment: From [Gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) -> *"to detect out-of-bounds and use-after-free bugs."*  No memory-leak detection.

Comment: Ah yes, seems there is also a 'leak' detector. I'm used to valgrind and thought sanitizer would behave similarly. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Memory leak detector, LeakSanitizer should be integrated into AddressSanitizer and is enabled by default in ASan builds of x86_64 Linux, see https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer. Try to set `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1`.

Comment: Hmm any idea how to do this using cmake? I tried using `set(ENV{ ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1})` without any joy.

Comment: Its unfortunate that the cmake integration is so confusing. I've had this tool work before and its output is really helpful. However, I don't have the time to mess around with getting it linked in. Back to valgrind for me it seems.

Comment: You should use `ASAN_OPTIONS` at run time, not at build time. If you have resulting binary, you can run it like this: `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [`ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html) while executing the binary to detect leaks. Using the example from the documentation

```
❯ cat leak.c
#include <stdlib.h>
void *p;
int main() {
  p = malloc(7);
  p = 0; // The memory is leaked here.
  return 0;
}
```

Compile the program

```
clang -fsanitize=address -g leak.c
```

and then execute it as follows:

```
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out
```

Output:

```
=================================================================
==63987==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x1034c109d in wrap_malloc+0x9d (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x4609d)
    #1 0x103477ef8 in main leak.c:4
    #2 0x7fff6b30fcc8 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1acc8)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Same for CPP

```
❯ cat memory-leak.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
};

int main() {
    char const* asanOpt = std::getenv("ASAN_OPTIONS");
    std::printf("%s\n", asanOpt);
    A* a = new A;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it

```
clang++ -g memory-leak.cpp -fsanitize=address
```

While executing the binary, use the option to enable leak detections

```
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out
```

Output:

```
detect_leaks=1

=================================================================
==69309==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 1 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x109ea556d in wrap__Znwm+0x7d (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x5256d)
    #1 0x109e4bf48 in main memory-leak.cpp:7
    #2 0x7fff6b30fcc8 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1acc8)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 1 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Tested on:

```
MacOS 10.15
```

With clang

```
clang version 10.0.1 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Hmm any idea how to do this with CMake? I tried using `set(ENV{ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1})` without any luck.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh I verified it for CPP and it works as shown in the example. As for CMAKE, I don't have much idea about it, but this option should be during the binary execution _and not the building stage_ (which is what CMAKE helps, no?). Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah okay I understand. In CLion its possible to ass env variables in the run configurations pane. It does not however turn on the memory leaks feature.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh See if the environment variable is actually reflected in the code? I've updated my answer to include the code for it.